# Why We need .Net Assembly Version

Tags: c#, .net

I think its a stupid question, sorry in advance. I am almost new to .Net Framework. I am reading about assemblies in .net. I am confused what is logical reason behind Assembly versioning.

Comment: If the version that the CLR finds at runtime isn't the one you promised to be available when you compiled the program then Very Bad Things happen.  Instead of nasty undiagnosable exceptions or the code just not doing what you expected it to do, you get a simple-to-understand FileLoadException.

Comment: My question is basic then this. what was the reason to give version of an assembly

Comment: My brain threw a FileLoadException at that comment.  Google "dll hell" to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, Hans Passant for the track. I found this after reading about "dll hell"

Comment: @user3256062 So you already get why assembly need version, or do you mean you asked this question after reading about dll hell?

Comment: No, after providing clue Hans Passant I have read about dll hell then I clear my point why assembly version required.

Comment: No after reading about 'DLL Hell'. I found the answer of my question. Thanks Hans Passant for this favor